# Write dll files from MSI to local directory

Tags: dll, wix, exe, windows-installer

I'm looking to package couple of DLL files (these are patch dll files for a third party software that we use) into an MSI and write them to a certain directory on the installer's machine. Then I want to write to windows registry to store the last installed version of the MSI. Having never done such a thing before, I need direction. Please suggest ideas on how to do this? WIX toolset?

Comment: I would note that you should be creating a patch not a second MSI.  Your design violates  the windows installer component rules and can cause troubles.

Comment: How do I create a patch to distribute these DLL's? Should it be provided by the same software company?

Comment: Ideally they should.

Comment: I just checked, they don't have a patch available. My only solution currently is to literally drop the dll files to C:\Program files\Software Company\bin location. They say I don't even need to install the dll files, I just need to overwrite their existing dll's with the new one's they give me and also update the registry to reflect the new version number of the software.

Comment: They aren't describing best practice.  You can use their install and dll's to create a patch.  I'm not very good at it in WiX because I use InstallShield quick patch projects in this scenario.

Comment: It's not the best practice, agreed. When you say installSheild, is it possible to store said DLL's in the patch and then write them to the bin folder?

Answer (score 0):

Any MSI tool can do this, in fact it would be pointless to have a tool that builds MSI files if it couldn't do this! If this is literally the only thing you'll ever do with MSI then you could even use Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition with the installer extension and be done in a day. I certainly wouldn't recommend VS if you were going to do more MSI work that requires more functionality than you describe. WiX would probably take longer because it exposes more of Windows Installer capabilities.

I don't think you need your "last installed version of the MSI". I suespect you're worried about updates if you get more versions of the MSI - in other words I think you see it as the solution to some problem that you didn't explain. The version of your MSI eill be in Program&Features anyway.

The scenario you describe sounds like a hot fix that the owning company doesn't have a proper fix for, which would be a patch or another MSI-based update, and not just dumping files to replace existing ones. Chris is correct - they have decided to not do the right thing (create a patch) and instead have left your company with the problem of managing the update.

Comment: Can you direct me to resources where I can learn how to package dlls into an MSI?

Comment: This is old but still relevant: https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/visual-studio/getting-started-with-setup-projects/